# Writing a constraint with gurobipy

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, linear-programming, gurobi

I shared the parameters, variables and notation of the model:

[image]

[image]

[image]

I have difficulty in writing equation 7, which is one of the constraints of the model, with gurobipy. The code block I wrote is as follows:

```
mdl2.addConstrs(T[i, j, k] >=  quicksum(p[l]*y[i, l, s] + s[l]*x[i, l, s] for l in N for s in ???)- d[j] - 100000*(1 - x[i, j, k])   
                for i in M
                for j in N
                for k in N) #7
```

Could you please help me about this? It will be very welcome. If desired, I can also share all the model code I wrote.

Answer (score 1):

You should be good with writing `s in range(k)` - the sum depends on the index `k` from the outer loop.

To make this a bit easier to read and comprehend, you might want to switch around the for loops like this:

```
for i in M:
    for j in N:
        for k in N:
            mdl2.addConstr(
                T[i, j, k]
                >= quicksum(
                    p[l] * y[i, l, s] + s[l] * x[i, l, s] for l in N for s in range(k)
                )
                - d[j]
                - 100000 * (1 - x[i, j, k])
            )
```

This assumes that `M` is `range(m)` and `N` is `range(n)`. And please note that I am using `addConstr` because there is just a single constraint in every iteration of the triple loop.
In any case, you should write out the LP file of the problem and check whether what you are modeling actually corresponds to the mathematical formulation.